# IIS Forms/cookies FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've worked with IIS for over a decade now, but we always used NTLM. New job = forms authentication. I've read for hours and I still can't wrap my head around exactly what this is doing or where exactly it should be called from: FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);

I put a cookie manger in Firefox and the website seems to be issuing an auth cookie if I have the above SetAuthCookie or not (which I'm calling after a successful forms authentication).

That said, if I pass the forms authentication and IIS issues an auth cookie regardless, what is SetAuthCookie getting me? And how can I tell if it is the one I set, or if it is the one IIS is issuing regardless?

I hate to ask a stupid question, but I'm just not understanding this one.

Comment: Forms authentication has little to do with IIS. It is purely implemented in ASP.NET, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs and has a completely different way to authenticate.

Comment: Could you show your web.config and login method?

Comment: <forms name="FormsAuthentication" path="/" loginUrl="sign-in.aspx" timeout="120"/>
    </authentication>

Comment: Membership and Rolemanger w/ directory access configured. Login calls a classfile that checks a mysql table for username and password. All seems to work, as far as you have to actually login to get to directories that are assigned to you via role membership.